# cannot 'sudo' inside of bash if statement

Tags: linux, bash

I've dual linux boot i'm newbie in bash

when running the following script i got strange error:

```
if [[ 'grep -i fedora /etc/issue' ]]; then
        echo "the OS is Fedora"
        $(sudo yum update -y && sudo yum upgrade -y)
else
        echo "the OS is Ubuntu"
        $(sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y)
fi
```

> error : ./server_update.sh: line 9: Loaded: command not found

Comment: can you run with set -x and provide more detail?

Comment: Your `if` condition is completely broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's attempting to execute the output of your apt-get/yum commands, lose the `$(..)`

You also have an issue at the start:

```
if [[ -n "$(grep -i fedora /etc/issue)" ]]; then
```

is the correct way to check if a string exists.

Your code should then look like this:

```
if [[ -n "$(grep -i fedora /etc/issue)" ]]; then
    echo "the OS is Fedora"
    sudo yum update -y && sudo yum upgrade -y
else
    echo "the OS is Ubuntu"
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
fi
```

Comment: You may want to fix the condition too.

Comment: Better still say: `if grep -iq fedora /etc/issue; then`

Comment: @devnull I'm never a fan of that, I know it works, but there's something to be said for grep returning success when there are results, even if it encounters an error. I'd much rather `grep` error and I check the output myself, than have `grep` hide any errors it might get because it's found a match. In most cases it's highly unlikely to occur, I've never seen grep crash, even when scanning binary files for unicode strings with complex expressions, but I'm that sort of person. :(

Comment: @scragar It was just a suggestion.  Choice is yours.  The current solution is much more vulnerable than using `-q`, though.